# How to find out which file is currently opened in vim?

Tags: vim

This may sound trivial but, on more than one occasion, I have found myself having forgotten which file in `vim` I have open (e.g. when I am looking through different log files and such) and the only way I knew how to find out was to close the file and look in the command history for the most recent command.

Is there a command within vim to tell you which file you currently have opened without exiting the program or the file you have opened (e.g. `:<which_file_cmd>`?)

Comment: If you didn't call `vim` with so many args, use `:args`.

Comment: Related: [How can I see the full path of the current file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/104/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In addition to [uprego's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104903/26909), you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (in normal mode) to get the current buffer's name as well as the total number of lines in it and your current position within it.

**Update**

As per [rxdazn's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104901/how-to-find-out-which-file-is-currently-opened-in-vim/104902#comment160712_104902), you can press <kbd>1</kbd> before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to get the full file path. If you press <kbd>2</kbd>, you get the full file path *and* the buffer number you currently have open (useful when you have opened multiple files with `vim`).

Comment: Like a lot of vim commands this also applies to the `less` command which I use when viewing files as opposed to editing.

Comment: also, pressing 1 before Ctrl+G gives you the file's full path

Answer (score 32):

```
:f
```

gives the name of file currently open.

Comment: brilliant and very minimalist

Answer (score 30):

When in `vim` I always use the `:ls` command.

#### Example

```
:ls
  1 %a   "blah.txt"                         line 1
```

Where `blah.txt` is the file's name.

Answer (score 9):

When `vim` is not called with *many* args, `:args` is helpful.

Comment: The other problem with this is that if the file was opened after vim was launched, it won't be listed.

Answer (score 4):

If you can have a default vim configuration file, you can add a `statusline` to always have file details available. I understand that if you're constantly remoting into different servers this won't be much help. Here's my slightly complex one pulled from my .vimrc.

```
" %F(Full file path)
" %m(Shows + if modified - if not modifiable)
" %r(Shows RO if readonly)
" %<(Truncate here if necessary)
" \ (Separator)
" %=(Right align)
" %l(Line number)
" %v(Column number)
" %L(Total number of lines)
" %p(How far in file we are percentage wise)
" %%(Percent sign)
set statusline=%F%m%r%<\ %=%l,%v\ [%L]\ %p%%

" Change the highlighting so it stands out
hi statusline ctermbg=white ctermfg=black

" Make sure it always shows
set laststatus=2
```

And it looks like this in MacVim (but works in terminals as well).
[image]

As always you can do `:help statusline` to get some more options and details. And checkout [*Learning Vim the Hard Way* ch 17](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/17.html) for a good explanation of statusline.

Comment: I always use statusline as well. +1

Answer (score 4):

I my vimrc I have this mapping

```
nnoremap <leader>pfn :echo expand('%:p')<CR>
```

So if I type `,pfn`, or "print file name", it echos the entire file path.

Answer (score 3):

There's also `:echo @%`, which gives you the name of the file relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

There countless ways to get this kind of info, but if you want something so that you only have to press a key and the filename will be displayed then insert the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
map <F4> <ESC>:file<CR>
```

This says,

```
bind the `F4' key to the following sequence: Escape-key, :file, Carriage-Return (enter-key)
```

And the `file` command, as is probably apparent, returns the name of the current file along with other info.

You could also setup a status-line so that you wouldn't even have to do anything but look.

To keep the status-line always insert the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set laststatus=2
```

This tells ViM to always display a status-line, other options are `0`, for never, and `1` for only when you have two or more windows open in ViM.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just type `:e`
and this shows me the full file path and number of lines and characters too.

*Caveat*: it reopens the file from disk essentially, so it's most useful when the file is already saved.

`:help :e` says:

> ```
>                           *:e* *:edit*
> Edit the current file.  This is useful to re-edit the
> current file, when it has been changed outside of Vim.
> This fails when changes have been made to the current
> buffer and 'autowriteall' isn't set or the file can't
> be written.
> ```