# How can I constantly see the current filename in vim?

Tags: vim

I am using vim and I need a way to always be able to see the file that I am working on without having to do `^G`.
I see the file name when I start vim but when I start to work and use various functions it gets lost.
Also I have seen other people have some kind of "addons" in the lower part of the vim console that seem like they are "button"/"tabs" (I am not sure how to describe them) that show various info constantly including the file name.
Any idea what are these plugins? Or how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: somewhat related:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104901/how-to-find-out-which-file-is-currently-opened-in-vim

Comment: Might you be thinking of https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can add this to your `.vimrc`file, or temporarily while in `vim`.

- vimrc - `set laststatus=2`
- in vim - `:set laststatus=2`

To get the full path you can add this command, again to either your `.vimrc` or while in `vim`.

- vimrc - `set statusline+=%F`
- in vim - `:set statusline+=%F`

#### Examples

*normal mode*

[image: ss #1]

*command line mode*

[image: ss #2]

For more info than you care to read through there's additional info on both of these available in `vim`.

```
:help laststatus
:help statusline
```

#### References

- [Displaying status line always](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Displaying_status_line_always)
- [5. Modes, introduction - *vim-modes-intro* *vim-modes*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#vim-modes-intro)
- [Learning the vi Editor/Vim/Modes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/Modes)
- [How can I permanently display the path of the current file in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488717/how-can-i-permanently-display-the-path-of-the-current-file-in-vim)

Comment: Weird name (no mnemonic I think). This does not seem to show the full path. Would showing the full path be an option?

Comment: @Jim - see updates

Comment: @Jim it's just as `ls` command `set ls=2`

Answer (score 14):

I find that adding the currently opened file name on the window title bar using

```
: set title
```

in the `.vimrc` looks like less obnoxious then always having the status bar taking up a full line at the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

The tabs you are probably referring to is not a plugin, but a [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) built-in. Try

```
:tabnew
```

It should open a new tab and you should see the menu bar, showing the name of the files in the different tabs. To always show this menu-bar, use

```
:set showtabline=2
```

Although this makes only sense when you really want to work with tabs (I can recommend it). Otherwise I'd suggest to set the name in the statusbar as outlined by others.

Comment: No.Not tabs for sure.I know about tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Tabs show the name of the file, that's what you want, no? You called them tabs yourself...

Comment: @Jim what's wrong with tabs?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Also check out [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline). Note that you still have to use "set laststatus=2" show the status line.

[image]

Comment: wow, will try it after finish this task!.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for full path:

```
:set statusline =%4*\ %<%F%*
```

More info: http://got-ravings.blogspot.com/2008/08/vim-pr0n-making-statuslines-that-own.html